# Reading a local file and displaying requested output to an html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, search, scripting

I have a local file generated by a python monitoring script I developed which outputs all it's data to results.do file via cron job periodically. My plan is to display only certain error information which may come back from the .do file. For example, if the script outputs 'processer high' then I want this to be displayed as 'Warning - CPU Above 80%' on an html file then copy this same method for all processes in the monitoring script. It sounds like it might be an easy job but I'm struggling to find my starting point and I haven't yet came across anything similar online.
Being fairly knew to scripting I'm not entirely sure how to tackle this and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction..

Hopefully this makes sense and please let me know if you would like me to clear anything up

So far, all I've found is a get function which will search for a file and display the ouput as an alert. My question is, is it possible to change the alert function to a search and then search it's contents for what I require then display my requested ouput if errors are displayed?

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get("results.do",function(data,status){
      alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can yougive a sample of how your results.do would look like?

Comment: Yes it is possible. How to do it is at best too broad and opinion based. In other words off topic.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend throwing regex at it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FRegular_Expressions

Search "data" for matches to: your ERROR text, then any characters, then newline.

And then just loop through and print out the matches, for example in paragraph tags.

EDIT -- here's how...

```
function filter(file) {
    var pattern = /ERROR.*/g
    var matches = file.match(pattern);

    for (var match in matches) {
        $('#myTarget').append('<p>'+match+'</p>');
    }
}
```

I would personally add error checking and CSS classes, and build all of the HTML as an array then append it all at once, and other cool things -- but then I'd just be doing your job for you. :)

- Kieron